# How to use new format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have the following query, but this one is old. There should be a new way of writing the following code. Can anyone tell me how i should write this:

```
$get_test = mysql_query("select test from test_table where id = '1'"); 
$test = mysql_result($get_test, 0);
```

Ik would like to write it in: MYSQLI instead of mysql.

Comment: `There should be a new way of writing the following code`. Can you explain a little more about what you are expecting. Any sample output..?

Comment: What library: PDO or MySQLi?

Comment: Thats the point i don't understand: How to choose between PDO or MYSQLI, i think mysqli ??

Comment: The change to mysqli, on the syntax side is very very minor; so I recommend it if you don't want to have to learn many new methods and new syntax.

Comment: Yes oke, so now is my question: How can i write above code in the MYSQLI format?

Comment: Did you try anything? MySQLi has good documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: See my answer below,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

Mysqli:

```
<?php 
$strSQL = "select test from test_table where id = '1'";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
  echo $result["test"]."
";
}
?>
```

PDO:

```
<?php
$id = 1;
try {
#connection
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB', $db_username, $db_password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    

    $data = $conn->prepare('SELECT test FROM test_table WHERE id = :id');
    $data->execute(array('id' => $id));

    while($rows = $data->fetch()) {
        print_r($rows);
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use PDO:

```
$db = new PDO("...");
$statement = $db->prepare("select test from test_table where id = :id");
$statement->execute(array(':id' => "test"));
$row = $statement->fetch();
```

Comment: and if i want to use mysqli?